# Getting 500 error trying to load view through controller rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, error-handling

Im trying to get a rails view to load through an ajax call. I get this error:

```
Started POST "/schools/municipalities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-07 13:40:11 +0100
Processing by SchoolsController#municipalities as HTML
  Parameters: {"Hallands län"=>nil}
  School Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "schools".* FROM "schools" WHERE "schools"."region" IS NULL
  Rendered schools/municipalities.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):
    1:
    2: <%= form_tag 'schools' do %>
    3: <p><%= select_tag(:municipalities, options_from_collection_for_select(@municipalities, :municipality, :municipality )) %>
    4: </p><p>
    5: <%= submit_tag 'Nästa', :class=> 'btn btn-primary' %>
    6:  </p>
  app/views/schools/municipalities.html.erb:3:in `block in _app_views_schools_municipalities_html_erb___826836004410337613_70142825095080'
  app/views/schools/municipalities.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_schools_municipalities_html_erb___826836004410337613_70142825095080'
  app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:10:in `municipalities'


  Rendered /Users/gjores/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/gjores/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/gjores/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (12.8ms)
```

I can se that Im getting the params all wrong. And im been trying to work out how this is supposed to be.

**school.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#region').change(function(){
        region = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:  "municipalities",
            cashe: false,
            data: region,
            dataType: "HTML",
            type: 'POST',

            success: function(html){
          $("#append").append(html);}

        });
    });
});
```

**schools.rb controller**

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  def region
    @regions = School.select(:region).uniq.order(:region)

  end

  def municipalities
    region = params[:region]
    @municipalities = School.where(:region => params[:region]).uniq!{|e| e[:municipality]} 
    render :layout => false

  end

  def schools
    @user = current_user
    @schools = School.where(:municipality => params[:municipalities])
    render :layout => false
  end
end
```

**Region view**

```
<%= form_tag 'municipalities' do %>
<p><%= select_tag(:region, options_from_collection_for_select(@regions, 'region', 'region')) %>
</p>
    <div id="append">

    </div>
<p>
<%= submit_tag 'Nästa', :class=> 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**Municipalities view**

```
<%= form_tag 'schools' do %>
<p><%= select_tag(:municipalities, options_from_collection_for_select(@municipalities, :municipality, :municipality )) %>
</p><p>
<%= submit_tag 'Nästa', :class=> 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The params is supposed to be :params => "Hallands län"

Comment: I belive that your "data" parameter in Ajax request is wrong. It should be "region=" + region. Try it.